# Java, Oracle - adding amounts

Tags: java, oracle

As far as I know, the best data type for financial calculations is `BigDecimal` in Java and we can add `BigDecimals` safely in contrary to `floats` or `doubles`.

I have a paged list of items and summary of all items to display. Paged list works fine but doesnt have summary amounts as I get only one page per request to server in my webapplication. I would like to make `Oracle` database do summary (using `sum()` and `groupby()` methods). But the question is does `Oracle` sums amounts properly? I mean it doesnt loose precision etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle you define precision and scale in type [NUMBER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832). And this type store and calculate exact value (unlike BINARY_DOUBLE, BINARY_FLOAT), with given precision. Maximum precision in Oracle is 38, see docs for more information.